# How can I check by hook whether there is a file deletion operation?

Tags: git, githooks

How can I check by hook whether there is a file deletion operation?

What I want is that I can get an email alarm if someone deleted a file in a certain commit.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to be notified (but still allowing that deletion to be pushed), you can write a `post-receive` hook on [the server side](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) (assuming you have control over that remote Git repositories hosting server).

That hook would [loop over the sent commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17371287/6309) and check for the [file deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28242302/6309)

```
#!/bin/sh
while read oldvalue newvalue refname
do
   if [ "$(git log -1  --diff-filter=D --summary $newvalue | grep filename)" ne "" ]; then
     # send email
   fi
done
```