# GIT hook updated T-SQL database on commit

Tags: git, t-sql, sql-server-2005, githooks, git-post-receive

I have googled this for an hour now and have yet to find a solution.  Is there a way to write a GIT hook that will put the git message from a commit into a SQL Server database on postreceive? What I'd like to do is store a table in my database with all my commits, and much like bitbuckets issue tracker, I would like to close issues in another table if the commit message is something like "close issue #2".

Comment: The way it's now, I'm not sure this question is a good fit for Stack Overflow. Have you chosen a programming language to write the hook? What have you got so far? What problems are you facing?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I'm only familiar with the default hooks for GIT, I was unaware you could use different programming languages.  I'm running in a windows environment. As far as the problems I'm facing I have no idea how to write the hook as the question indicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a script which knows how to update your sql server database, then it is a matter of writing a post-receive hook which collect the log message for each received commit.

You can take an idea in:

- "[git post-receive hook that grabs commit messages and posts back to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263186/git-post-receive-hook-that-grabs-commit-messages-and-posts-back-to-url)".
  Extract:

  ```
   for revision in `git rev-parse --not $other_branches | git rev-list --stdin $revspec`; do
     # I don't know if you need to url-escape the content
     # Also you may want to transmit the data in a POST request,
     wget "http://server.com/logthis.asp?msg=$(git log $revision~1..$revision)"
   done
  ```
- [campfire post-receive hook](https://github.com/edouard/campfire-git-post-receive-hook/blob/master/hooks/post-receive).
  Extract:

  ```
  text = `#{GIT} log --all --since='#{revtime}' --reverse`
  ```
- "[`fogbugz-git-integration`](https://github.com/philipf/fogbugz-git-integration/blob/master/post-receive)", which is close to what you are looking for, as it parses the commit message, looking for certain keywords.
  Extract:

  ```
  git log $oldrev..$newrev --pretty=format:~~CommitSubject:%s%n~~CommitHash:%H%n~~EOR%n | while read logentry;
    do
      # Parse out the commit subject
      if [ "${logentry:0:15}" == "~~CommitSubject" ]; then
         ...
  ```